# AngularJS Promise does not run a digest

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

I am new to promise concepts and I'm facing a problem while I'm trying to submit a login form.

When the promise is resolved, I want to update the UI by changing the value of a scope variable.

Here is the controller method which is called

```
 $ctrl.loginForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid

    if (isValid) {
      LoginService.login($ctrl.user).then(function (value) {
          $ctrl.loginError = false;
          var cookie = value.token;
      }, function (reason) {
          $ctrl.loginError = true;

      });
    }

  };
```

and here is my service method

```
  service.login = function(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $http.post(AppConst.Settings.apiUrl + 'api-token-auth/',credentials).success((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      }).error((err, status) => {
        reject(err, status);
      });
    });
  };
```

So once the promise is resolved the `$ctrl.loginError` in the controller changes its value but it does not update on the UI.

I've tried with `$apply` and it works, but I don't understand why I must use `$apply`! I thought that the digest cycle starts by default!

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: no need to resolve promise like this in service. you can directly return your http call

Comment: The $http service return a promise that trigger a digest after handled. Not need to wrap that on a native promise. You should accept @Denis Reshetniak answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` methods return you a promise which is a $q service. So, problem is that you use native promise wrapper which doesn't tell angular's scope to run $apply method.
Change your service to following

```
service.login = function(credentials) {
  return $http.post(AppConst.Settings.apiUrl + 'api-token-auth/',credentials);
};
```